# javascript how to get parent class constructor parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

I am pretty stuck right now on this, how can I get a parent class constructor's parameter? I want to get the Lion's DNA, then pass it to the baby lion and use it. Note that this isn't really for my personal use but rather it's a package / module, so I can't enter what I've entered in my code.

Example code:

```
class Lion {
    constructor(client, DNA = {}) {
        this.sharp = howsharp;   
        this.client = client;
    }
}

class BabyLion extends Lion {
    constructor(client) {
        super(client, How can I get DNA??);
    }
}
```

Things I've tried:

- `super(client)` and `super(client, {somestuff})` - Doesn't work obviously, because I am chaging the DNA of the Lion that has been declared beforehand.
- Having an empty variable `let dna`and then doing `dna = DNA` and then exporting it - 'obviously' did not work.

Comment: The question doesn't really make sense; when you call `super()` you can either pass `DNA` or not pass it. What *would* make sense (and be consistent with actual reality) would be for there to be a method on `Lion` to make a new `BabyLion`.  You have to have an *instance* of `Lion`, in other words.

Comment: But I want to pass the DNA that the user specified when declaring the Lion class.

Comment: You're confusing the declaration of the class and the instantiation of a `Lion` instance. You could also have one of the arguments to the `BabyLion` constructor be the parent `Lion` instance.

Comment: The chain of events when constructing an instance of a subclass is that the subclass constructor is called *first*. If that subclass constructor has a `super()` call, like yours does, then the superclass constructor function runs and initializes the base object. *Then* your subclass constructor can run. There's only one object involved, however; the superclass `Lion` contents are part of the same object as the newly-constructed `BabyLion`.

Comment: ```DNA``` property is accessible in constructor parameters in ```Lion``` as well as in ```BabyLion```

Comment: @dorintufar If `BabyLion` doesn't declare a `DNA` parameter, then no, it's not accessible. Whence would it come?

Comment: @deceze I expressed myself bad. New one: If you declare ```DNA``` parameter in ```BabyLion``` constructor and pass it in super, then ```Lion``` can access ```DNA``` parameter from constructor props.

Comment: in fact, you can access ```DNA``` (with your implementation) this way: set ```DNA``` as class property in ```Lion``` class then access property in descendant class (```BabyLion```) after ```super``` call

Comment: I would call the subclass `Cub`

Answer (score 1):

You don't "get the parent's parameter", you need to define all the necessary parameters in your overridden constructor and then pass those to `super()`:

```
class BabyLion extends Lion {
  constructor(client, DNA) {
    super(client, DNA);
  }
}
```

You may add more parameters to `BabyLion`'s `constructor`, or fewer, but your child's constructor needs to somehow get and pass all required parameters to the parent's constructor. E.g.:

```
class BabyLion extends Lion {
  constructor(client) {
    super(client, 'foo');
  }
}

class BabyLion extends Lion {
  constructor(client, DNA, bar, baz) {
    super(client, DNA);
    this.bar = bar;
    this.baz = baz;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Lion {
 constructor(sharp, client) {
  this.sharp = sharp
  this.client = client;
 }

 getSharp(){
  return this.sharp;
 }
}

class BabyLion extends Lion {
 constructor(sharp, client) { // Here you can use more BabyLion parameters 
  super(sharp, client);
 }
}

a = new BabyLion(1, 2)
a.getSharp(); // returns ==> 1. This way it gets other attribures from Lion class
```

Answer (score 0):

If this helps.

```js
class Lion {
    constructor(client, DNA = {}) {
        this.sharp = 'howsharp';   
        this.client = client;
        this.dna = DNA;
    }
}

class BabyLion extends Lion {
    constructor(client) {
        super(client);
    }
    printDna() {
        console.log(this.dna);
    }
}

var baby = new BabyLion('hoper');
baby.printDna();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty unclear what you want to do.  But if you want to mimic parents -> child inheritance, then something like this could work:

```js
const mix = (dna1, dna2) => Object.keys(dna1).reduce(
    (strand, key) => Object.assign(strand, {[key]: Math.random() < .5 
      ? dna1[key] 
      : dna2[key]
    }), {}
)


class Lion {
    constructor(name, DNA = {}) {
        this.name = name
        this.DNA = DNA;   
    }
    
    mate(partner, name) {
        return new Lion(name, mix(this.DNA, partner.DNA))
    }
}

const father = new Lion('Mufasa', {foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3, qux: 4})
const mother = new Lion('Surabi', {foo: 5, bar: 6, baz: 7, qux: 8})

const child = mother.mate(father, 'Simba')

console.log(child)
```

This does not use inheritance as used in software.  (A baby lion is still just another lion.)  But the baby does (randomly) inherit its genes from each parent.

And I'm assuming that this has little to do with what you actually want.  But beware of thinking too literally about inheritance if this is just a dummy example.  There is a real difference between real-world inheritance and the programming concept.